# Git trouble pushing to github repository

Tags: git, github

I want to push a remote folder to Github (`git@github.com:myProject/Myproject.git`), I connect to my remote server vis ssh then I type in my git repo :

```
git add myFolder
git commit -m "add my folder"
git remote add origin git@github.com:myProject/Myproject.git
 >>fatal: remote origin already exists.
git push -u -f origin master
>>Password for 'https://anotheruser@bitbucket.org':
```

I think I need to change maybe the remote folder from Bitbucket to github or what ?

Comment: use `git remote add origin https://github.com/myProject/Myproject.git` instead of `git remote add origin git@github.com:myProject/Myproject.git`

Comment: @wt.cc that is not the problem here. The problem is that OP already has a remote called `origin` and therefore cannot add a new remote with the same name.

Comment: oh, sorry, you need `git remote rm origin` firstly

Comment: @1615903 But would there be any unintended consequences of changing the URL without actually removing and adding a completely new one?

Comment: @wt.cc seems like it worked but after  sudo git push -u -f origin master I get fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Then your credentials are probably wrong, or Github doesn't recognize your public SSH certificate.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no. The behaviour is exactly the same in both cases. And besides, the answers in the duplicate cover both cases.